# Magento Search Results

Tags: php, magento

For some reason when doing a search it doesn't show the pagination , instead it shows the url

Has anybody got any ideas? I've been searching for ages and can't find any solutions that work.

Cheers

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using? Can you reproduce this behavior with the default theme? Are you referring to the free text search functionality?

Comment: I've put it back to the defualt theme and it's still happnening, on version 1.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, it's a conflict with an installed extension - great!